# YTD calculations for Fiscal Years with multiple fiscal years

Tags: excel

I know there are excel YTD calculations posted, but I am trying to do this for multiple fiscal years. See example results I'd like to get through excel; this suggests that a fiscal year begins in April and ends in March of the following year.

```
Date           Sessions       YTD (Calculation I need)
4/1/15         400           400
5/1/15         100           500
10/1/15        600           1100
1/1/16         800           1900
4/1/16         100           100
5/1/16         200           300
6/1/16         300           600
1/1/17         400           10000
```

I am thinking I need to do a SUMIF with defined start and end dates based on an index match?

Thanks Much!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use this:

```
=IF(MONTH(A2)=4,B2,SUM(C1,B2))
```

[image]

Comment: What happens when the fiscal year changes?